# Visual Studio Code , How do I copy file or folder from one branch to another?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, how do I copy file/folder from one branch to another branch?

Through command line, I can do that using below command.

`git checkout branch_A -- Folder\Folder1\file.txt`

Comment: I know you're asking how to do this in VSCode, but what's wrong with just doing it on the command line?

Comment: Given that you only want a VSCode answer, I've removed the two irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio Code you can install GitLens extension which gives you more control over Git.

Using GitLens you are able to compare two branches.
[image: compare branches]

In the Search & Compare tab you can compare the file between the branches to see the changes and you can open the file from the other branch, while still being in your current branch.
[image: compare files between branches]

Once you open the file from your other branch, while still in your current branch, simply go to File > Save as and overwirte the file in your current branch.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the GitLens steps suggested by shev.m, which are really helpful, and have one tweak that worked better for me. Once you find the file in the Search & Compare tab, you can right click on it and select Restore (Checkout), which will modify the file on your current branch with all the changes from the other branch, and those changes will be Staged changes. Now, if there's a conflict, you'll have to resolve it, but this avoids having to save over the current branch file.